# ListView in ArrayAdapter gets mixed up when scrolling, any ideas?

Tags: java, android, listview, scroll, android-arrayadapter

I really need your help. I've got an ArrayAdapter in a ListView with items and category separators. When I scroll the order gets mixed up and there seems to be other issues as well. Can you provide me with help, suggestions or input about my code?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    holder = null;
    Watch = (Watch)filtered.get(position);
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (type) {
        case Watch .TYPE_WATCH :
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            break;
        case Watch.TYPE_SEPARATOR :
            LayoutInflater vi2 = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi2.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
            break;
        }
    } else { 
        holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
    }
    switch (type) {
    case Watch.TYPE_CARD :
        if (o != null) {
            holder.textView1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
            holder.textView2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
            if (holder.textView1 != null)
                holder.textView1.setText(o.getName());
            if (holder.textView2 != null)
                holder.textView2.setText(o.getPosition());
        }

        break;
    case Watch.TYPE_SEPARATOR :
        if (o != null) {
            holder.SeparatorTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_header_title);
            if(holder.SeparatorTextView != null) 
                holder.SeparatorTextView.setText(o.getName());

        }
        break;
    }
    v.setTag(holder);
    return v;
}
```

I have also overriden getItemViewType and getViewTypeCount, are those necessary to display? Are they necessary at all? All kind of help would be appreciated! I've been stuck with this for a while now!

Comment: convertView is a view that is being utilized/restored (list view works like that, it loads only some elements that are to be visible to the user). So when you inflate your convertView reference, you inflate every time some other location of that view

Comment: Ok, am I correctly inflating in my code? I would really appreciate some help on this issue.

Comment: At which exact point you are getting some weird results? which condition is executed when it happens?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this thread. The code displayed above is correct. The problem was my implementation of getViewTypeCount(), it returned an incorrect value, but thank you for your kindness when you tried to help!

Comment: Nice work Sane. As a friendly reminder, can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.